# Duplicate Question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Q1: [Rajya sabha member and Election in India](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/rajya-sabha-member-and-election-in-india?rq=1)

Q2: [How are the members of the Indian upper house elected?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/76433/how-are-the-members-of-the-indian-upper-house-elected/76434#76434)

They are exact duplicates of each other.

Q1 is older but Q2 is better framed and the answer to Q2 is more complete in some sense.
What should be done?

Comment: Did you flag/vote to close either of them as a duplicate of the other one?

Comment: Vote to close the least useful one as a duplicate of the most useful one. Age is not only not the first factor to consider, it is not a factor to consider at all.

Comment: @JoeW I hadn't until Nij's comment. Was just trying to understand what should be done in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

You should just vote to close the least useful one as a duplicate of the other one. Once you have done that it will get into the close vote queue and other users will be able to help with the process.